# Errors JSX that I cannot understand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, jsx

I wanted to execute a simple Instruction from the click event of the button but it indicates a lot of errors to me and I cannot understand the problem. I have tried to do as explained in the React site guide but it's not good anyway. Here is the code.
Could you help me? Is the syntax actually wrong?

The error is(it is written in Italian which would be my language):
[{
"resource": "/c:/Users/Alberto/Desktop/MeteorProject/myApp/imports/ui/App.jsx",
"owner": "typescript",
"code": "1005",
"severity": 8,
"message": "È previsto ','.",
"source": "ts",
"startLineNumber": 5,
"startColumn": 9,
"endLineNumber": 5,
"endColumn": 14
}]

```
export const App = () => (
  const click = () => (
    let message = 'Ciao come stai?',
    return(
      <b>{message}</b>
    )
  ),
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
    <button onClick={click}>Clicca</button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: can't return a html content on click function. onClick is void

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems there:

- Your `click` function can't *return* the content; the return value of the click function isn't used at all.
- You're trying to use the concise form of the arrow function for `App`, but you have a statement in the body (`const click = ___`). The concise form can only have expressions, not statements. Use the full function body form (with a `{` just after the `=>`) instead.

**If** your goal is to change the message when the button is clicked, put the message in state and update the state from your click handler:

```js
const { useState } = React;

/*export*/ const App = () => { // <== Need full function body, we have statements in it
    // Start with the initial state
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("Welcome to Meteor!");
    const click = () => { // <=== This *could* use (), but using a full body makes it easier to add later
        // Update state
        setMessage("Ciao come stai?");
    };
    return (
        <div>
            {/* Show the current value of `message` */}
            <h1>{message}</h1>
            <button onClick={click}>Clicca</button>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

In the above, I stuck to simple text (not least because the usual styling of `h1` elements would make a `b` inside the `h1` not do anything), but it *is* possible to store React elements in state as well. Doing so is unusual, but possible:

```js
const { useState } = React;

/*export*/ const App = () => { // <== Need full function body, we have statements in it
    // Start with the initial state
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("Welcome to Meteor!");
    const click = () => { // <=== This *could* use (), but using a full body makes it easier to add later
        // Update state with a React element
        setMessage(<b>Ciao come stai?</b>);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            {/* Show the current value of `message` */}
            {/* Used a `div` instead of `h1` so you could see the boldface */}
            <div>{message}</div>
            <button onClick={click}>Clicca</button>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```js
export const App = () => {
const [btnClicked,setIsBtnClicked] = useState(false)
let message = 'Ciao come stai?'
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
    <button onClick={() =>setIsBtnClicked(!btnClicked) }>Clicca</button>
    {btnClicked && <b>{message}</b>}
  </div>
  )
}
```